# UiGrid data dissappears in pagination

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I using UiGrid to show data that I get in a endpoint.

I want to update the name of the columnsDefs when I click on the paginators buttons. The name is changed correctly but the data in the rows of the column that I update they dissappear

I do not know what's happening. Any Idea?

Here the code.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

      var paginationOptions = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 25,
        sort: null
      };

      var i = 0;

      $scope.gridOptions = {
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        useExternalPagination: true,
        useExternalSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [
          { name: 'name' },
          { name: 'gender', enableSorting: false },
          { name: 'company', enableSorting: false }
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function(grid, sortColumns) {
            if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
              paginationOptions.sort = null;
            } else {
              paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
            }
            getPage();
          });
          gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
            paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
            paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
            getPage();
            test();
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].name="Test"+i;
            gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
            gridOptions.columnDefs.splice(0,gridOptions.columnDefs.length)

          });
        }
      };

      var test = function(){
        i++;
      };

      var getPage = function() {

        var url;
        switch(paginationOptions.sort) {
          case uiGridConstants.ASC:
            url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100_ASC.json';
            break;
          case uiGridConstants.DESC:
            url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100_DESC.json';
            break;
          default:
            url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json';
            break;
        }

        $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = 100;
          var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
          $scope.gridOptions.data = data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
          $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
        });
      };

      getPage();
    }
    ]);
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVLobUTA0MRm5mBnB5yi?p=preview)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name is confusing the grid, `displayName` property to the rescue!

All thee must do is change `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].name="Test"+i` to this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].displayName="Test"+i;
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eMO6MYlPC1QzAFNirfLI?p=preview

Comment: Yes, you right. I saw the error earlier, I did not update this question, I forgot. Thanks for answering.